# CSS only cross browser clipped corners?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have a modern CSS method for doing something like this? I've been searching for ages. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?

http://fu2k.org/alex/css/equalheight/divs/clipped

UPDATE:

Thanks to all for the replies & comments. Unfortunately the background of my div is patterned and has a thin solid border so this seems to rule out a lot of suggestions. I'm still exploring the ideas. Perhaps a javascript approach is a possibility?

Comment: IE does not support this - at all

Comment: Check out http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure CSS - cross-platform, working down to IE7 (I haven't tested this with IE6, but I think it should still work).

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
div.big {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background:#FFF url(images/pattern.png)
    border: solid 1px black;
}

div.top-left-b {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-top: solid 40px black;
    border-right: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.top-left-w {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border-top: solid 40px white;
    border-right: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.top-right-b {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-top: solid 40px black;
    border-left: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.top-right-w {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    border-top: solid 40px white;
    border-left: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.bottom-left-b {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid 40px black;
    border-right: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.bottom-left-w {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border-bottom: solid 40px white;
    border-right: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.bottom-right-b {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom: solid 40px black;
    border-left: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.bottom-right-w {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    border-bottom: solid 40px white;
    border-left: solid 40px transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
-->
</style>

<div class="big">
    <div class="top-left-b"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="top-left-w"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="top-right-b"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="top-right-w"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="bottom-left-b"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="bottom-left-w"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="bottom-right-b"><!-- --></div>
    <div class="bottom-right-w"><!-- --></div>
</div>
```

This would produce the following effect:

[image]

Comment: This is cool but I guess the box can't have a background image?

Comment: Well, that depends. You can have background image set to the box - and it would still work.  Notice the `transparent' color on each of the corners' css - that would just show what's underneath, being that an image or a solid colour.

Comment: Cool yes - tried it and this is a pretty good solution! The only problem for me is that it doesnt allow a 1px border around the shape. I may have to look at some hacky alternatives i think.

Comment: You could immitate 1px black border with a bit more hackery at css - just lay out 2 boxes over each other shifted by 1 px.  I'll try hacking this - and post results.

Comment: I have updated my answer to create white box with clipped corners and 1px black border.

Comment: Works a treat - Thanks Aleks!

Answer (score 2):

For rounded corners, you can use the [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius) (with and without vendor-prefixes).

If you really want the same look as in the image at the question, you can use two containers, and applying CSS-[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) (with and without vendor-prefixes) + [`overflow:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow) to get the desired look.

A fallback has to be used for older browsers which do not support these methods, by using a transparent background image.

### Demo + further explanation of logic at: http://jsfiddle.net/7upkc/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-clipped-box">
    <div class="inner-clipped-box">
        <div class="content-clipped-box">
            Content here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (vendor-specific prefixed for crossbrowser support, ignored Opera and IE in this case):

```
.outer-clipped-box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner-clipped-box {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ddf;

    -moz-transform-origin: 140px 84px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 140px 84px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 140px 84px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* Undo rotation, to get the content in the right position*/
.content-clipped-box {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;

    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0,70px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0,70px);
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0,70px);
}
```

Comment: Cool sounds promising - looking forward to the demo! I dont need much backward support since its just a style feature but I'd love it to work in modern webkit, IE & geko

Comment: @cronoklee Have a look at the updated answer. May look big, but many lines are just duplicates to enable support across multiple browsers.

Comment: Cool thanks for this Rob. Does this method allow a background image on the shape?

Answer (score 1):

There is no modern css for this, only for rounded corners. But you can draw clipped edges with old-school borders. Look at this example http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/borders/stacked-cubes.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Google for "CSS diagonal corner" or triangle but the only example I recall reading used tricks. [Here's an example of a triangle](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) that you might use to insert into a corner and set opacity or some such. But [this might have better info on that](http://battletech.hopto.org/html_tutorials/rounded_css_borders/more_styles.html).

EDIT: Even better than all that is the one I should have referred to in the first place: [Stu Nichol's site.](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/search.html?cx=partner-pub-6651950180071236%3achrtwm-4ria&cof=FORID:10&ie=UTF-8&q=corners&sa=%20Search)